# Galaxybase failed to access visualization

Tags: graph-databases

After successfully launching Galaxybase, I attempted to access the visualization page through my browser but encountered a failure.

The page at port 51314 doesn't load, and I receive an error message indicating that the visualization access has failed. I have confirmed that the port is not being used by any other processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be a problem on network connection, such as firewall policy not opening the corresponding port. The firewall configuration policy and setup method are detaild in Chapter 3 Installation and Deployment#Installation Requirements#Configuration Requirements#Configure Access Ports